Inconsistency between TensorBoard logged values and Terminal outputs
I am working on a Image Segmentation project. Going to the point, in the TensorBoard logger the recorded metrics and loss values are significantly different than what can be seen in the terminal, as the learning epochs go by.
However, if I take a look at the values returned in the terminal, for example I can see that: mean_iou value is consistently above 0.50, yet in the CSV Logger & TensorBoard the recorded value for mean_iou in that epoch is 0.36.
I cannot see where the issue could be created. I used the same training workflow as always and I have never experienced such issue.
Thanks in advance to anyone who could answer.
I tried to investigate this issue online, but couldn't find anything of this type. I also added a CSV Logger to compare the results, and those match with the TensorBoard ones.

Please verify metric calculations and ensure that TensorBoard averages the metrics over an epoch. To better understand and resolve the issue, please provide more details about your model architecture, TensorFlow/Keras versions, and relevant code snippets, especially those related to metric logging and mean_iou calculation. This will help us understand and resolve the problem better.
